# auto import classname Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

i see teacher in a tutorial of Reactjs he type : `nav.navbar`

and magically `<nav className="navbar"></nav>`   appear. Can some one help me to explain it and how to do this. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

That is [emmet notation](https://docs.emmet.io/cheat-sheet/).

At the basics, it will transform a selector: `nav.navbar` into the HTML (well, JSX) markup equivalent matching that selector: an element with a `nav` tag name with a class name of `navbar`.

How to do this will depend on your IDE. For VSCode, [for example](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/react-shortcuts-that-will-instantly-boost-your-productivity/):

> 1. Go to Code (at the top of your screen), then Preferences, then Settings in VSCode
> 2. In the options on the left, select Extensions, then Emmet
> 3. Scroll to the Include Languages section, add in the item input, javascript and in the value input, javascriptreact and hit Add Item

Comment: can you add the "keyboard shortcut" to transform from emmet script into html? It should be mostly the key `tab`

Comment: [link]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I2UBjN5ER4s&t=626s.  Here is the link of this lesson. at the time ** 10:23** i do not know how it works. Thank you